# Firefox change browser-close prompt default option to Stay on page

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Currently I am using onbeforeunload to detect a browser-close event, however, I also want to make 'Stay on page' the default option, currently the default highlighted option is 'Leave Page'. I have done research on this, it seems like Firefox just does not allow us to modify the prompt, but I really need to make 'Stay on page' the default option, is there any workaround?

Or is there another way to detect a browser-close event, so I could code my own custom dialog to achieve the same thing.

Cheers!

Comment: No, there is no workaround, and this is intentional.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank you for the quick response, I thought so as well, is there any another way to detect the browser-close thought? I just want a function that detects a browser-close event, prompt the user to save any data, but the highlight option should be 'stay on page', I tried to simulate a 'TAB' key press, so can switch the focus on the 'Stay on Page' button, but it seems to not work on a prompt.

Comment: No, there is absolutely no way to do that. If there were, that possibility would be a bug in Firefox. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Hi Ryan, it is a client requirement, but now I guess it is not possible to implement this function. It is a asp.net web-app, maybe I should see if there is anything I can do on the server side to detect a browser-close event. Cheers.

Comment: If this is for something enterprisey, you can create a browser extension to change the prompt’s default. I don’t know if that’s acceptable or worth it for your needs, though.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I will have a look into browser extension :)